# TypeScript/Angular2: tagDef.requireExtraParent is not a function

Tags: firefox, typescript, angular, transpiler, es6-shim

Researching the error,

> "EXCEPTION: TypeError: tagDef.requireExtraParent is not a function"

and it actually returns 0 results on Google.

**Background:**

- site works fine on Chrome and Safari.  haven't tested IE yet.  whole separate nightmare there.
- error is only for Firefox (seems all versions.  Currently on 45 though)
- I'm converting from TypeScript down to ES5 using System, following along with the Angular quickstart
- On a mac if that matters
- Angular2, beta 9

The site is very basic.  I've removed all possible complications and it appears that the error is just in bootstrapping itself.  Perhaps a missing polyfill?

**index.html**

```
<script>
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript', 
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
    packages: {
        'js': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    } 
  });
  System.import('js/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

**main.ts (entry point)**

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />

import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app/components/app';
import 'rxjs/Rx'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]); // if i comment this out, the error disappears indicating that it lives somewhere in app.ts.
```

**app.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: "myapp",
    templateUrl: "templates/app.html",
    directives: [],
    providers: []
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

**What have I tried**

Adding some additional polyfills, like html_parser which appears to be where the requireExtraParent method is defined.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/lib/html_parser.js"></script>
```

Eliminate any compilation/transpiling errors.

Digging so deep that Google can't even find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a reserved word in Angular as a tag (watch).

```
<services></services>
<collage></collage>
<watch></watch>  <== problem
<collage></collage>
```

changing it to this works:

```
<services></services>
<collage></collage>
<watchit></watchit>  <== works fine
<collage></collage>
```

this was impossible to debug.  i had to go line by line commenting things out until eventually i figured out it was in the html, and eventually which line in particular introduced the problem.

posting only so if someone else hits this, they don't go so crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is spoton

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/lib/html_parser.js"></script>
```

Comment: The error remains after doing so, though...?  SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module